# Merge based on 2 columns values - Check for duplicate key values error

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have two data tables with the following columns - `ddate,fnumber,file,model` and `fnumber,ddate,model,model_id,file`. I would like to update the first table with values from the second table matched by `ddate` and `fnumber` columns.

If I use `merge`:

```
dtPT <- merge(dtPT, dtAT, by = c("fnumber", "ddate"), all.x = TRUE)
```

then I get the following error -

> Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin) NULL else
>   as.integer(max(nrow(x),  :    Join results in 8568291 rows; more than
>   8537179 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i,
>   each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If
>   that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that
>   j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure
>   you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise,
>   please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow
>   and datatable-help for advice.

I tried to search for duplicated records in `dtAT`:

```
setkeyv(dtAT, c("fnumber", "ddate"))
dtAT[duplicated(dtAT)]
```

but it returns 0 rows.

I also tried to use `match` instead, but it doesn't work as I expected (sample data is used below):

```
tPT <- "ddate,fnumber,file,model
2014-05-26,S71149,ps1.csv,320
2014-09-26,,ps2.csv,
2014-10-16,,ps3.csv," 

tAT <- 
"fnumber,ddate,model,model_id,file
S71149,2014-05-26,319,VU-BHP,as1.csv
S71149,2014-05-25,320,,as2.csv
S71149,2014-05-23,322,VU-BTP,as3.csv"

columnClasses <- c("POSIXct", "factor", "character", "factor")
dtPT <- read.csv(text=tPT, header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = c(""), colClasses = columnClasses)
dtPT <- as.data.table(dtPT)

columnClasses <- c("character", "POSIXct", "character", "factor", "factor")
dtAT <- read.csv(text=tAT, header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = c(""), colClasses = columnClasses)
dtAT <- as.data.table(dtAT)

dtPT$model_code <- dtAT[match(paste(dtAT$fnumber, dtAT$ddate), paste(dtPT$fnumber, dtPT$ddate)), dtAT$model]
```

The code above in result assigns `model_code` values to all rows:

```
        ddate fnumber    file model model_code
1: 2014-05-26  S71149 ps1.csv   320        319
2: 2014-09-26      NA ps2.csv    NA        320
3: 2014-10-16      NA ps3.csv    NA        322
```

when `320` should assigned to the first row only:

```
        ddate fnumber    file model model_code
1: 2014-05-26  S71149 ps1.csv   320        319
2: 2014-09-26      NA ps2.csv    NA         NA
3: 2014-10-16      NA ps3.csv    NA         NA
```

Since for second and third rows there is no match by combination of `ddate` and `fnumber`.

(the `merge`, of course, works well with the example below, but returns the error with Production data)

Comment: Are there `NÀ` values in your key-columns?
Maybe they cause problems

Comment: What's your data.table version? There were some corner cases fixed in `1.9.5` to ensure the error occurs only when `i` has duplicates. I'd recommend trying with [1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), and if you still get the error, you definitely have duplicates in `i`. If you're sure too, and want to proceed, set `allow.cartesian=TRUE` as the error message tells you.

Comment: @Arun, data.table version is 1.9.4

Comment: @Floo0, there are no `NA` values

Comment: I think there is a missing letter 'A' in `dtAT[duplicated(dtT)]`?

Comment: could you please show the expected output.. I'm having a hard time understanding your point about "320" being assigned to first row.. Also you say "merge" works well here... but it returning error is your issue, isn't it?

Comment: @Arun, two cases are discussed here - Production (with 8537179 rows in `tPT`) and the Sample. So, I don't have any problems with `merge` and the Sample case, but it returns given above error with Production case. I will update the question to answer 'the expected output' part.

Comment: I see.. thanks. Just looked at the post again. You should be checking for duplicates only on the columns you join by.. That is.. `dtAT[duplicated(dtAT, by=c("fnumber", "ddate"))]`. Could you update with what you get for `sum(duplicated(dtAT, by=c(...)))`? Thanks. PS: will add an issue to make error message more clear on `merge`, when it fails, as to what `i` is..

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to update the first table with values from the second table

Instead of `merge` function there is a *update on join* feature in data.table, it will be faster as it updates by reference and don't need to materialize bigger dataset after joins.
The general syntax is

```
DT1[DT2, value := i.lookup_value]
```

So going to your example

```
library(data.table)

tPT <- "ddate,fnumber,file,model
2014-05-26,S71149,ps1.csv,320
2014-09-26,,ps2.csv,
2014-10-16,,ps3.csv," 

tAT <- "fnumber,ddate,model,model_id,file
S71149,2014-05-26,319,VU-BHP,as1.csv
S71149,2014-05-25,320,,as2.csv
S71149,2014-05-23,322,VU-BTP,as3.csv"

columnClasses <- c("POSIXct", "factor", "character", "factor")
dtPT <- read.csv(text=tPT, header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = c(""), colClasses = columnClasses)
dtPT <- as.data.table(dtPT)

columnClasses <- c("character", "POSIXct", "character", "factor", "factor")
dtAT <- read.csv(text=tAT, header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = c(""), colClasses = columnClasses)
dtAT <- as.data.table(dtAT)

setkeyv(dtPT, c("fnumber","ddate"))
setkeyv(dtAT, c("fnumber","ddate"))

dtPT[dtAT, model_code := i.model]
#         ddate fnumber    file model model_code
# 1: 2014-09-26      NA ps2.csv    NA         NA
# 2: 2014-10-16      NA ps3.csv    NA         NA
# 3: 2014-05-26  S71149 ps1.csv   320        319
```

If you get mentioned error you should start by checking duplicates but not on full rows but on your composite key. The simple code below.

```
dtPT[,.N,c("fnumber","ddate")][N>1L]
dtAT[,.N,c("fnumber","ddate")][N>1L]
```